# In Oracle, how do you use two different functions on the same column?

Tags: string, oracle, function

I am trying to use two different string functions (initcap and trim) on one column and I would like it to display only the one column with both functions applied.  In general how do you use two or more functions on a single column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you can nest function calls within function calls, evaluated innermost to outermost:

```
SELECT INITCAP(TRIM(column)) FROM your_table;
```

As long as each nested function returns a value of a compatible type, you should be able to apply this to any functions.

For example:

```
SELECT '|' || INITCAP(TRIM('  abc def ghi  jklmn   ')) || '|' str
  FROM dual;
```

Results in:

```
STR
--------------------
|Abc Def Ghi  Jklmn|
```

Note I concatenated the pipe symbol to illustrate the TRIM of the string.

More to the point here:

```
SELECT '|' || INITCAP(TRIM('.' FROM '... abc def ghi  jklmn...')) || '|' str FROM dual;
```

Gives me:

```
STR
----------------------
| Abc Def Ghi  Jklmn|
```

Comment: I tried select initcap(trim('.' from goals)), and that doesn't work for me as I am sure I am not entering it correctly.

Comment: @Christopher...  the 'from goals' part goes outside the parentheses.

Comment: Isn't that an example for the whole table?  I am just trying to do the trim and initcap for one column in a table.  This is probably very easy for most, but I am new and am having syntax issues.  Goals is the column name.

Comment: What version of oracle? It works for me. When you say it doesn't work, is there a message? Different output than expected?

Comment: @Randy, no the syntax given is correct. See my latest update.

Comment: I put SELECT personid, initcap (personlname), initcap(personfname), initcap(trim(‘.’ from goals)),
FROM Employees1
ORDER BY personlname;
and then I get ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: You've got an extra comma before your FROM clause, after your last expression in the select list.

Comment: Ah, now it works.  I appreciate your patience and all the help :)